# Iterate through folders (with spaces in names) and change file name inside to folder name

Tags: bash

Im trying to solve the issue to automate file rename process from:

```
/subfolder 1/0123.txt
/subfolder 2/13134.txt
```

to:

```
/subfolder 1/subfolder 1.txt
/subfolder 2/subfolder 2.txt
```

I tried things like:

```
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
for dir in */; do mv "${dir}"*.txt "${dir}"`echo "${dir%\}"`.txt; done
IFS="$OIFS"
```

or:

```
for dir in */; do   mv "${dir}"/*.txt "${dir}"/"${dir}".txt; done
```

but I end up with problem of either spaces or trailing "/" in folder name

Comment: I think you need `mkdir` not `mv`

Comment: @Jetchisel - not really - I want to change the only txt file inside of the folder, so it has the same name as the files parent folder.

Answer (score 2):

I think you get a more tweakable code with `find` (this one is GNU version):

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c '
    file=$1
    fulldir=$(dirname "$file")
    dir=${fulldir##*/}
    mv "$file" "$fulldir/$dir.txt"
' findshell {} \;
```

This finds all `.txt` files in the directories one level below the current one, as specified by `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth`. So it will find `./subfolder 1/0123.txt` but not `./x.txt` nor `./subfolder 1/subsubfolder 1/0123.txt`.